# Symmetry of the Riemannian curvature tensor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, tensors

The Riemannian curvature tensor, in local coordinates, $R_{ijkl}$, has the following symmetries:
$$R_{ijkl}+R_{jikl}=0;$$
$$R_{ijkl}+R_{ijlk}=0;$$
$$R_{ijkl}=R_{klij};$$
$$R_{ijkl}+R_{jkil}+R_{kijl}=0.$$
These algebraic identities give the degree of the freedom of curvature to be $\frac{1}{12}n^2(n^2-1)$. where $n$ is the dimension of manifold. I believe, but have trouble to show, that these identities completely describe the pointwise symmetries of the curvature tensor, i.e. given any $\frac{1}{12}n^2(n^2-1)$ numbers, we can find a Riemannian manifold such that the curvature tensor $R_{ijkl}$ evaluated at certain point, in some local coordinate, is of these particular numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A positive answer (and much more!) can be found in

"Riemannian Metrics with the Prescribed Curvature Tensor and all Its Covariant Derivatives at One Point" by M. Berger and O. Kowalski, Mathematische Nachrichten, 
Volume 168 (1994) Issue 1, p. 209-225.

If your library does not have the journal, you can probably get it through some form of an interlibrary loan.

Comment: Dear down-voter: Could you please explain what you did not like in this answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it would have been better to include [a link](https://sci-hub.se/https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mana.19941680113) or, even better, a summary of the proof. Such a summary makes the answer self-contained, but at the very least it'd help to pinpoint which theorem therein is crucial (5.2, by the looks of it).